# Amazon mechanical turk- "DoesNotExist" value for Comparator in qualificatiol type assignment

Tags: amazon-web-services, comparator, mechanicalturk, java

My goal is to prevent the people who worked on my HITs previously to work on my next HITs.

For this goal, after posting the first HITs, I assigned a qualification type naming "already_done_myHITs" to the workers who worked on my first round of HITs.

Then for posting the second HITs, I am going to create a QualificationRequirement which has the "DoesNotExist" value to its Comparator, **but I cannot see this value in the list of values that the imported libraries suggest me.**

I think, I need to use "DoesNotExist" value instead of X in below code; however, the list of suggestions only contains "Exists" and I do not see "DoesNotExist" one.

QualificationRequirement[] qualReq = new QualificationRequirement[1];

qualReq[0] = new QualificationRequirement();

qualReq[0].setQualificationTypeId(qualID);

**qualReq[0].setComparator(Comparator.X);**

qualReq[0].setRequiredToPreview(false);

(I think if I use the qualification_type_ID that I assigned to the previous workers in posting the second HITs, then using the Comparator.DoesNotExist, I can ban the first HITs' workers from working on next HITs)
Do you have any suggestion for this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe that only the [Java SDK](https://requester.mturk.com/developer/tools/java) and [Ruby SDK](https://requester.mturk.com/developer/tools/ruby) for Amazon Mechanical Turk is up-to-date with the DoesNotExist qualification comparator. You can learn more about the recently updated Java SDK [here](http://blog.mturk.com/blog/2016/03/updates-to-our-java-sdk.html).

Note that the [Perl](https://requester.mturk.com/developer/tools/perl) and [.NET](https://requester.mturk.com/developer/tools/net) SDKs, along with the [Command Line Tools](https://requester.mturk.com/developer/tools/clt) do not support the [DoesNotExist comparator](http://mechanicalturk.typepad.com/blog/2014/07/new-qualification-comparators-add-greater-flexibility-to-qualifications-.html) (yet).

It looks as though you're using the Java SDK, so you should be in a good place. Here's an example that you can drop straight into the SimpleSurvey.java code sample in the SDK. It should appear in the `createSimpleSurvey()` method. Just replace these lines:

```
  // The create HIT method takes in an array of QualificationRequirements
  // since a HIT can have multiple qualifications.
  QualificationRequirement[] qualReqs = null;
  qualReqs = new QualificationRequirement[] { locationQualReq, numHITsApprovedQualReq };
```

with this:

```
  // This is a built-in qualification -- user must NOT be a Mechanical Turk Master Worker
  QualificationRequirement notMasters = new QualificationRequirement();
  notMasters.setQualificationTypeId("2ARFPLSP75KLA8M8DH1HTEQVJT3SY6"); // You can get these values here: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSMechTurk/latest/AWSMturkAPI/ApiReference_QualificationRequirementDataStructureArticle.html
  notMasters.setComparator(Comparator.DoesNotExist);

  // The create HIT method takes in an array of QualificationRequirements
  // since a HIT can have multiple qualifications.
  QualificationRequirement[] qualReqs = null;
  qualReqs = new QualificationRequirement[] { locationQualReq, numHITsApprovedQualReq, notMasters };
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer! 
The problem was related to version of JAVA SDK. I was using java-aws-mturk 1.6.2 and now I updated that to version 1.7.0. So, the problem was gone!

I am going to use the same strategy that you mentioned; however, instead of using the predefined qualifications, I want to use different qualifications. My goal is to ban the workers who worked on my HITs previously from working on my new HITs.

Answer (score 0):

Problem was related to version of JAVA SDK. I was using java-aws-mturk 1.6.2 and now I updated that to version 1.7.0. So, the problem was gone!
Now the list of Comparator's values contains the "DoesNotExist" value!